# RestKit KVC Validation won't call validation methods

Tags: validation, core-data, restkit, kvc

this is my first question here :)

OK so I have a projet with ReskKit 0.23.3 via cocoapods. I use RestKit/CoreData.

I fetch an URL, the result got mapped to my object and is correctly saved by core data. I want to use Key-Value Validation to check some values retrieved against the one already persisted. I read that i could use the methods `validateKey:error:` on my `NSManagedObject`. Somehow, it is never called. I'm frustrated...

Here are my files (for simplicity, i concatenated logic code into one flat file here):

**JSON response /collections/{id}**

```
{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000",
    "image_url": "http://server/image.png",
    "name": "Collection C",
    "etag": 42,
    "ctag": 42
}
```

**Collection.h**

```c
@interface Collection : NSManagedObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *collectionId;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSURL *imageUrl;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *etag;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *ctag;

@end
```

**Collection.m**

```c
@implementation Collection

@dynamic collectionId, name, imageUrl, etag, ctag;

- (BOOL)validateCollectionId:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
    NSLog(@"Validating id");
    NSLog(@"Coredata collection id: %@", self.collectionId);
    NSLog(@"GET collection id: %@", (NSString *)*ioValue);
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateEtag:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
    NSLog(@"Validating etag");
    NSLog(@"Coredata collection etag: %@", self.etag);
    NSLog(@"GET collection etag: %@", (NSString *)*ioValue);
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**Code**

```c
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/MyApp.sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server/api"];

RKObjectManager *objectManager  = [self managerWithBaseURL:url];
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
objectManager.managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];

RKEntityMapping *collectionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Collection" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[collectionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"collectionId",
                                                        @"image_url": @"imageUrl"}];
[collectionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name", @"etag", @"ctag"]];
[collectionMapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"collectionId"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *collectionResponseDescriptors = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:collectionMapping
                                                                                                   method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"collections/:collectionId"
                                                                                                  keyPath:nil
                                                                                              statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:collectionResponseDescriptor];

[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"collections/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    Collection *collection = (Collection *)[mappingResult.array firstObject];
    NSLog(@"Collection: %@", collection);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Oh noes :(");
}];
```

**Output**

```
2014-09-13 12:39:04.242 MyApp[41958:607] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit logging initialized...
2014-09-13 12:39:05.028 MyApp[41890:607] Collection: <NSManagedObject: 0x9108a60> (entity: Collection; id: 0x94166d0 <x-coredata://6645F428-7631-45F0-A8AF-E2352C50F35E/Collection/p1> ; data: {
    collectionId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000";
    ctag = 42;
    etag = 42;
    imageUrl = "http://server/image.png";
    name = "Collection C";
})
```

So, I get my Log with the Collection, but None of the NSLog in the `validate<Key>:error:` methods got triggered... Could not figure out why!

**Edit**

With some breaks, i figured this is RKMappingOperation who is responsible for calling those validation methods on my object. Precisely it's `validateValue:atKeyPath:`

RKMappingOperation.m

```c
...
- (BOOL)validateValue:(id *)value atKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    BOOL success = YES;

    if (self.objectMapping.performsKeyValueValidation && [self.destinationObject respondsToSelector:@selector(validateValue:forKeyPath:error:)]) {
        NSError *validationError;
        success = [self.destinationObject validateValue:value forKeyPath:keyPath error:&validationError];
        ...
    }
...
```

But `self.destinationObject` is an `NSManagedObject` and not a `Collection` object...

**Console**

```
(lldb) po [self.destinationObject class]
NSManagedObject
```

I hope you could lead me to the right way :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have not specified that the entity should use the `Collection` class in the Core Data model. If you don't specify anything then `NSManagedObject` will be used by default.

[image: Demo image from the web]

Comment: Damn! I lack experience in CoreData... Thank you sir! :)